# Difference between 'eat' and 'eating' in context of following sentence

Tags: verbs

What is the difference between 'eat' and 'eating' in the context of the following sentences:

> When I see them **eating**, I feel compelled to eat.
>   When I see them **eat**, I feel compelled to eat.

Comment: For all practical purposes there's no difference between using the present participle ***eating*** or the unmarked infinitive ***eat*** in your exact context.

Comment: [There's usually a difference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing), and I think *eating* would be the more common choice here because it's when you see them while they're in the process of eating that you get hungry or whatever – but you might as well have seen them eat, and then felt the urge. (Google Books searches ([1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22when+I+see+them+eating%22&tbm=bks), [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22when+I+see+them+eat%22&tbm=bks)) seem to confirm this.)

Answer (score 1):

I think although both can be used interchangeably and as @FumbleFingers mentioned, for practical purposes there's no difference.
However, I think they're sometimes used differently, depending on the situation.

> When I see them **eating**, I feel compelled to eat.

When you see them eating, they're in the process of eating and you'd usually (not always) say this while seeing them eat.

For instance:
you're with a friend and you're watching *them* eat. You then whisper over to your friend "When I see them eating, I feel compelled to eat."

> When I see them **eat**, I feel compelled to eat.

In this case you're generally saying every time you see them eat, you feel compelled to eat.

For instance: 
you're with a friend, and you're talking about *them*, and then you say 
"When I see them eat, I feel compelled to eat."